# can't use migrate with sail laravel

Tags: laravel-artisan, laravel-8, laravel-sail

Hi I've just tried and to install Laravel 8 with sail and I've run into a problem

What I've done is to first run the curl one-liner from laravel's own page

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/sail-test | bash
```

once that finished I did as it said and run

```
cd sail-test && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Everything started as it should, I can connect to the database, I can see the site on http://localhost however I get the following error when trying to migrate:

```
$ sail artisan migrate:install

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 

      +29 vendor frames 
  30  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Do i need to change anything in the `.env` file or do I need to do any other changes first?

Comment: Do you have a password set in your .env file?  If so you probably need to set `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` to 'no' in your docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First (this command will return your mysql container IP address):

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name_or_container_ID>
```

Second in your .env file:

```
DB_HOST=<ip_address_returned_from_command_above>
```

And then:

```
$ sail artisan migrate
```

Edit:

Just add to your DB_HOST env var the name of your database container:

```
...
DB_HOST=mysql
...
```

Comment: I'm getting the same response after trying this

Comment: Worked for me except only with root username and blank password

Comment: You can also use the name of the docker image (found in docker-compose.yml). By default that is `DB_HOST=mysql`

Comment: Worked for me after replacing DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 with DB_HOST=mysql (the name of the docker image)

Comment: container_name_or_container_ID   =??
how can get container_name_or_container_ID ?

Comment: DB_HOST=mysql this work for me

Answer (score 5):

You need to artisan command by login in sail. Here are the steps.

1. Go to your project directory and run the following command

   sail shell
2. After that command you will be logged in your container and you can run the artisan migrate command.

Answer (score 0):

change the port of XAMP MySQL from 3306 to any other port. Sail migration works when the local port should be 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in 2024 with WSl2 and Ubuntu 22.04.

I solved it, either with the method in @Gabriel Fonseca's answer,

or this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
# Docker MYSQL NAME
DB_HOST=Docker mysql name --> see on docker container and see what is the name for mysql container
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=projectname
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3306 --> add this too, I found this at laracast discussion
```

after that I used this in bash/cmd terminal:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: `FORWARD_DB_PORT=3306` is not necessary, because it's the default.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me. Hoped it helps.

```
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it it very similar to the other answer and doesn't explain much, not even that your code that not formatted as such should go to the .env file. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).