# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'cookies-project'

Tags: mysql, laravel

I use Laravel to connect MySQL database in my pet-project.

I use `sail up -d` after `yarn dev` to start the project. Working with DataGrip.

But I can't `php artisan migrate` because I have error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'cookies-project'.

I tried to change `localhost` , `127.0.0.1`. Use command: `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan optimize:clear` but nothing work. Have the same error.

What I'm doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't use migrate with sail laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267604/cant-use-migrate-with-sail-laravel)

Comment: No. I tried to this answer. Now I have error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.

Comment: Is it working when you change your db name to sail?

Comment: At what plan? I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm recently started learning programming

Comment: in your .env you can change your database credentials. Where you have already specified your database name as `cookies-project`. And I am asking you to change it to `sail` and try again to connect database. Did you even created a database in DataGrip with exact same database credentials in your .env?

Comment: Well, I try your advice. It's still not working. Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'sail' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = sail and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Yeah, in DataGrip I create database with same credentials

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and for me I had to stop the mysql server installed on my computer it's worked

Not mamp or wamp server !

Try this

For Mac :
brew services stop mysql

Windows :
C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"

C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqladmin" −u root shutdown

Linux:
service mysql stop